# How to pick Decision Trees algorithm's parameters a-priori?

Tags: parameters, machine-learning, grid, decision-tree

I would like to make some predictive/classification task using the DT algorithm. However, if I don't want to go through the grid search method to identify the optimal parameters, how can I go about in deciding the value of the parameters (such as tree depth and minimal sample to split) apriori?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Otherwise these would not be hyperparameters but simply constants, built in into the model. The whole reason of something being a hyperparameter is lack of well established training/choosing method. There are plenty of things besides grid search, including (but not limited to): random search, metaoptimization, Bayesian optimization of hyperparameters, etc. But in the end - you cannot run from it.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the regularization parameter in logistic regression and SVM, isn't it a common practice to choose an arbitrary default value say at 1 a-priori? If so, why is it OK to pick some value in them but not in DT?

Comment: No, it is not a common practise. This is a common mistake. However some models are less sensitive to choice of hyperparams (like linear svm) and some are more (dt). More sensitive it is - more need for tuning